# Same Combo Box on different sheets

Tags: excel, combobox, excel-2013, vba

I suppose this could apply to any `Form` control in Excel. I have a combo box that gets values from a `ControlData` sheet. I create a `Combo Box` in another sheet that references the `ControlData` sheet's cells where the list values are.

I can copy that `Combo Box` object onto different sheets, but when I change the properties on that object on one sheet (say, change the range where the values come from) then it only gets changed on the sheet where I changed the properties. I want to universally change the properties so I only have to do it once.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

> but when I change the properties on that object on one sheet (say, change the range where the values come from) then it only gets changed on the sheet where I changed the properties.

You directly can't change the properties of one control and expect the properties to change for the rest of the control **automatically**. If all of them refer to the same range then any change that you make in the **range** will be reflected in the rest not the object properties.

Having said that... Is it possible to change to the properties of one and expect it to be carried forward to the rest?

**Yes**. The **catch** is you will have to use VBA for that.

To make this happen, you will have to write a separate macro which will will loop through all the comboboxes in all the sheets and then change the properties.

In the below example, I am just going to change one property. You will have to manage for the rest.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        '~~> Loop through all the sheets
        For Each shp In ws.Shapes
            '~~> Since you copied the combo across,
            '~~> they will have the same name. Change as applicable
            If shp.Name = "Drop Down 1" Then
                '~~> Set their range
                shp.ControlFormat.ListFillRange = "Sheet1!A1:A20"
            End If
        Next
    Next ws
End Sub
```